# Swing JTextPane compilation error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package texteditor;
//import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class TextEditor {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        //JMenuBar menuBar = window.getJMenuBar();

        //Create menu bar
        JMenuBar menuBar= new JMenuBar();
        //File Menu
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JTextPane textArea= new JTextPane();

        Document d= textArea.getDocument();

        window.add(textArea);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
source code - cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Document  
location: class texteditor.TextEditor   at
texteditor.TextEditor.main(TextEditor.java:33) Java Result: 1 BUILD
SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Document` used in `JTextPane` is contained in a separate `text` package. Add the import:

```
import javax.swing.text.Document;
```

Comment: is not the wild card suppose to import all the classes in java,swing?

Comment: The wildcard will only import all classes from a _single_ package (not sub packages). You must specify the package name, `javax.swing.text` in this case. See [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - **cannot find symbol symbol: class Document**

You need to import an appropriate class called Document.

Comment: is not the wild card suppose to import all the classes in java,swing?

Comment: Yes, but it will not include the contents of sub-packages. Document is in `javax.swing.text`, so `javax.swing.*` will not pick it up.

You need to import `javax.swing.text.Document`.